# iloc[column,0] in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this is right for me to ask, but I am having trouble understand this For loop with iloc in it.
I am having trouble understanding what this line is doing `hr_new['ID']=hr_new[column_list.iloc[column,0]]`

Can anyone help with this?

code:

```
    column_list = pd.DataFrame(['ColA','ColB','ColC','ColD'])

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for column in range(len(column_list)):
    hr_new=hr.copy()

    hr_new.dropna(subset=[column_list.iloc[column,0]], inplace = True)

    
    hr_new['ID']=hr_new[column_list.iloc[column,0]]
    

    merged_data = pd.merge(hr_new, dataframenotshown, how='left', left_on='ID', right_on ='IDtwo')

    
    final_df = final_df.append(merged_data)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? 
iloc is used to select a cell/row/column based on its index
[Doku](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Comment: not my code, but I believe it is looping through each column and trying join with `dataframenotshown`  and trying to match every value from column_list with it. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also rewrite the code as

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(4):
    hr_new=hr.copy()
    hr_new.dropna(subset=[column_list.iloc[i,0]], inplace = True)
    hr_new['ID']=hr_new[column_list.iloc[i,0]]

    ...
```

Now you can see i is a value between 0 and 3 (len(colum_list) == 4).

Selecting (multiple) Rows/Cols using iloc would look like this:

- data.iloc[row_1, col_1] # select one cell
- data.iloc[[row_1,row_2,row_3,row_4], [col_1,col_2,col_3]] # select multiple cells
- data.iloc[:, col_1] # select one column
- data.iloc[row_1, :] # select one row

So the code:

```
hr_new['ID']=hr_new[column_list.iloc[i,0]]
```

EDIT:
The code Selects the column 'ID' from hr_new and fills it with the column of hr_new[x] where x is the value stored in the column_list by selecting rows of column 0.

In my opinion, this is a very complicated way to do this.
Consider storing the Column names as a list and iterate over them instead of  creating a dataframe and selecting rows.

```
column_list = ["col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"]
for col in column_list:
     hr_new=hr.copy()
     hr_new.dropna(subset=[col], inplace = True)
     hr_new['ID']=hr_new[col]

...
```

This should work the same way if I understand your code correctly

Comment: hey raavgo, could you edit your answer to include the merged data and final df part of mine code? Why didnt you use final df?

Comment: @Jonnyboi because it was not contributing to the answer.